# Do I need to keep the old ID3D11Device around after querying for ID3D11Device5?

Tags: directx11

When attempting to create a directx11 device using the newer `ID3D11Device5` interface the compiler complains that `ID3D11Device5**` is incompatible with `ID3D11Device**`.

Research via docs.microsoft (RIP msdn) says that the proper way to create a version 5 device is to call `QueryInterface` on a `ID3D11Device` to get a `ID3D11Device5`.

**Do I need to keep the pointer to a temporary ID3D11Device around after calling QueryInterface to get a ID3D11Device5 or can I release it as shown below?**

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

struct AdapterInfo {
    IDXGIAdapter4* adapter = nullptr;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC3 desc{};
    void Release() noexcept {
        if(adapter) {
            adapter->Release();
            adapter = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

//...

struct DeviceInfo {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL highest_supported_feature_level{};
    ID3D11DeviceContext* dx_context = nullptr;
    ID3D11Device5* dx_device = nullptr;
};

//...

DeviceInfo CreateDeviceFromFirstAdapter(const std::vector<AdapterInfo>& adapters) noexcept {
    //Snip Error handling...
    DeviceInfo info{};

    unsigned int device_flags = 0U;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    device_flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
    device_flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

    std::array feature_levels{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
    };

    auto first_adapter_info = std::begin(adapters);

    //Snip Debug/Logging output...

    auto first_adapter = first_adapter_info->adapter;
    bool has_adapter = first_adapter != nullptr;

    //Create a temporary "old" device
    ID3D11Device* temp_device{};
    auto hr_device = ::D3D11CreateDevice(has_adapter ? first_adapter : nullptr
        , has_adapter ? D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN : D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE
        , nullptr
        , device_flags
        , feature_levels.data()
        , static_cast<unsigned int>(feature_levels.size())
        , D3D11_SDK_VERSION
        , &temp_device
        , &info.highest_supported_feature_level
        , &info.dx_context);

    //Snip error handling...

    //Ask old device for newer interface.
    auto hr_dxdevice5i = temp_device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Device5), (void**)&info.dx_device);

    //Snip error handling

    //Release old device.
    temp_device->Release();
    temp_device = nullptr;
    return info;
}
```

Comment: Under the COM model, wouldnt querying the interface and retrieving the object add a reference to the parent object.  Therefore, releasing the original object should be safe for your Device5 interface.  It should be safe, but there are more experienced devs on here might be able to confirm/deny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is perfectly acceptable. The refcount on the underling device is up by one from `QueryInterface` and then back down by one from the release of the `ID3D11Device` interface so it's back where it started.

Note that you should strongly consider using a COM smart-pointer rather than trying to do all the ref stuff manually. [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) is the defacto standard here.

BTW, I do the same thing you are doing in my [device creation blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

> One issue that I see in your code is that it only works on Windows 10. On Windows 8.1 and Windows 7, you will get an `E_INVALIDARG` error passing in that list of feature levels. See the blog post for details. Of course, if you require `ID3D11Device5` then you already require Windows 10 (15063) or later.

Comment: The requirement for Windows 10 or later is intentional. :)

I really don't like the ComPtr system; I've already created my own Render Hardware Interface abstraction layer with its own RAII types.

Comment: You win. I refactored my entire engine backend/RAII types to use ComPtr. 30+ files and several thousand LOC. It was painful but made the code easier to debug. Nearly all destructors are now either no longer needed or simply declared default.

Comment: WRL::ComPtr was briefly a defacto standard, then Microsoft started to include ATL into free community editions of visual studio. CComPtr from ATL is way more usable. It does not need these GetAddressOf/ReleaseAndGetAddressOf/etc every single time you use the smart pointer, it’s casting them automatically. They are also compatible with `IID_PPV_ARGS` macro.

Comment: ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` is basically ATL's ``CComPtr`` version 2, and is available in every version of the Windows SDK back to Windows 8.0 SDK. ATL has a mixed history of availability as you note, and in VS 2017/VS 2019 is an 'optional' component so you can't always rely on it being present on a dev's system. The change in ``operator&`` behavior was intentional to stop memory leaks in traditional COM programming. Both are compatible with ``IID_PPV_ARGS``. In any case, *either* smart-pointer is a better choice for COM programming than raw pointers.